# Laravel Method [index@index] does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I had Laravel 4.2 application and updating it to Laravel 5.4. for this i have installed fresh Laravel 5.4 and migrated routes,controllers views etc.

I want to protect all pages after /warehouse e.g /warehouse/dashboard,/warehouse/accounts and so on except /warehouse/login page. I have searched and used this route but its not working properly.

Can any one let me know whats the proper way of authentication.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
         // uses 'auth' middleware
         Route::resource('/warehouse','WarehouseController@index');
    });
```

My login and verify routes are

```
Route::get('/warehouse/login', array('as' => 'WarehouseAdminLogin', 'uses' => 'WarehouseController@login'));

Route::post('/warehouse/verify', array('as' => 'WarehouseAdminVerify', 'uses' => 'WarehouseController@verify'));
```

Comment: Show me content of `WarehouseController@login`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Route:resource`  there is no need to add function name after controller.

So try this:

```
Route::resource('/warehouse','WarehouseController');
```

And for `Auth` middlware you can do this :

```
Route::middleware(['auth']->group(function() {
  // Auth routes
});
```

And it's obvious that login route should no be inside `auth` middleware! 
How can a new guest user see login page? 
Use Auth routes outside the `auth` middleware :

```
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
```

Comment: What about middleware and unauthorized access? @Ahmad

Comment: did that now if i try to access /warehouse without login it gives me Route [login] not defined.

Comment: @DanishJamshed  trying to get `auth` routes without loggin  redirects user to the login page

Comment: its giving me page not redirecting properly on firefox and too many redirects in chrome... my login page url is /warehouse/login

Comment: Obviously `login` route should not be in `auth` middleware!!

Comment: login route is not in middleware.

Comment: @DanishJamshed  See Updated answer again!!

Comment: Check my updated question. added login and verify routes